# ValueError: rename: src too long for Windows on python

Tags: python, rename, valueerror

I am not a programmer but I tried to automate renaming thousands of files using python. but this error appear. I've tried to shorten the path using win32api, using `\\?\` notation before the path, even moving the folder to drive C:\ to shorten the path but the error still exist. I want the name of files to add 0 depending how many the files are. ex: if I have 2000 files, I want the name to be x0000,x0001, x0012, until the last x2000

```
import os, win32api

def main():
    i = 0
    path = "C:/New folder/"
    path = win32api.GetShortPathName(path)
    while i < len(os.listdir(path))+1:
        filename = os.listdir(path)
        s = len(str(i))
        p = "x" + ("0" * (4-int(s))) + str(i) + ".jpg"
        my_dest = p
        my_source = path + str(filename)
        my_dest =path + my_dest
        os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
        print(my_dest)
        i+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir(path)` returns a list of filenames, not a single filename. You must iterate over this list:

```
import os, win32api

def main():
    path = "C:/New folder/"
    path = win32api.GetShortPathName(path)
    filenames = os.listdir(path)
    for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):
        my_source = path + filename
        new_name = 'x%04d.jpg' % i
        my_dest = path + new_name
        os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
        print(my_source, my_dest) # print both

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

On one of my local directories I print (without renaming):

```
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/.htaccess C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0000.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angucomplete-alt C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0001.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular-route.min.js C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0002.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0003.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular2.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0004.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular3.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0005.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular4.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0006.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular5.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0007.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/angular6.html C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0008.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/authorization.py C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0009.jpg
C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/authorization.pyc C:/Booboo/ANGULA~1/x0010.jpg
etc.
```

Comment: ok, that's explain things. also what does this code mean? 'x%04d.jpg' % i

Comment: `%` in one context is the remainder operator (for example 7 % 2 == 1). But in this context being applied against a string it is the [String Formatting Operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html). In this case the value of `i` is being substituted in the string expression `'x%04d.jpg'` replacing `%04d`. `%04d` says that the `%` string formatting operator should expect an integer argument and should replace this format specification padded with zeroes so that the total length is 4.